# How to create table by giving width option?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create table.

Below is my code:

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open) { con.Close(); }
    con.Open();
    string s = "CREATE TABLE ["+"" + rchtxtFieldCode.Text + "] "+ " (" + rchFieldTitle.Text + " " + combDataType.Text + "("+txtWidth.Text+")" + ")";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
    if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() >= 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("created");
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

It is creating table. But, it is showing exception when the datatype is int or text.

I want every datatype to function properly.

Comment: what type of exception its throwing?

Comment: Add conditions to handle int and text which don't have width?

Comment: "Incorrect syntax near ')'."-when not specifying anything in  txtWidth.Text

Comment: "Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot specify a column width on data type int."-when specifying something in txtWidth.Text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
string width = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtWidth.Text.Trim()) ? string.Empty : "(" + txtWidth.Text.Trim() + ")"
string s = "CREATE TABLE [" + "" + rchtxtFieldCode.Text + "] " + " (" + rchFieldTitle.Text + " " + combDataType.Text + width + ")";
```